# core dump error when generating vertex array with LWJGL3

Tags: java, opencl, lwjgl

So im trying to start using LWJGL3 and i want to make a simple window that draws 2 triangles with the vertices stored in the GPU. i keep on getting this error when i run the code A fatal error has been detected by the Java

```
Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f92f01996ec, pid=4580, tid=0x00007f93664c4700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_171-b11) (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.171-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [liblwjgl_opengl.so+0x446ec]  Java_org_lwjgl_opengl_GL30_nglGenVertexArrays__IJ+0xc
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

Here is my code

```
 private void loop() {
    // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
    // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
    // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
    // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
    // bindings available for use.
    GL.createCapabilities();

    // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
    // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

        glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);


        glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers
        // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
        // invoked during this call.
        glfwPollEvents();

    }
}

private void initTriangle() {

    FloatBuffer vertBuf = MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat(vertices.length);
    vertBuf.put(vertices);
    vertBuf.flip();

    vaoId = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoId);



    vboId = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuf, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

I am calling InitTriangle before the loop and i get the error at vaoId = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();

anyone that could tell me what im doing wrong or lead me in the right direction, i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called initTriangle before i made the GLCapabilites